# c# covariance with Interface and BindingList

Tags: c#, interface, covariance, bindinglist

Could not understand problem here:

```
public interface ILinkedTabularSectionManager<out T1> where T1 : TabularBusinessObject
{
    T1 LinkedTabularBusinessObject { get; }

    BindingList<T1> DataSource { get; }
}
```

> C# Invalid variance: The type parameter must be invariantly valid on.
>   is covariant.

Error is related to BindingList declaration.

Thanks.

Comment: `BindingList <T>` doesn't allow its type parameter variance.

Comment: Any workaround on this? In order to have BindingList was there?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How this interface must be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A covariant interface can only return covariant generic types that use the type varable. That means the return value of the `DataSource` property must also be covariant. `BindingList` is not covariant, so it can not be returned by a method or property of a covariant interface. The closest covariant interface to a `BindingList<T>` is `IReadOnlyList<T>` (`BindingList<T>` implements it), so you might want to use this one:

```
public interface ILinkedTabularSectionManager<out T1> where T1 : TabularBusinessObject
{
    T1 LinkedTabularBusinessObject { get; }

    IReadOnlyList<T1> DataSource { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When declaring variant type, you're limited to the single variance kind.

E.g., if `T1` is covariant (your case) none of interface members can use invariant or contravariant data types:

```
// This is valid: T in IEnumerable<T> is covariant
public interface ILinkedTabularSectionManager<out T1> where T1 : TabularBusinessObject
{
    T1 LinkedTabularBusinessObject { get; }

    IEnumerable<T1> DataSource { get; }
}

// This is invalid: T in BindingList<T> is invariant
public interface ILinkedTabularSectionManager<out T1> where T1 : TabularBusinessObject
{
    T1 LinkedTabularBusinessObject { get; }

    BindingList<T1> DataSource { get; }
}

// This is invalid: T in Action<T> is contravariant
public interface ILinkedTabularSectionManager<out T1> where T1 : TabularBusinessObject
{
    T1 LinkedTabularBusinessObject { get; }

    Action<T1> SomeAction { get; }
}
```